# How to Mono, PHP and .NET module run together on Ubunty Hardy at Slicehost?

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, mono, ubuntu-8.04

I'm running a rails app and PHP at my SliceHost Ubuntu Hardy Heron vps server. I've a `PdfProcess.exe` module built upon ASP.NET (.NET 2).

I've one PHP file which uses a `passthru("PdfProcess.exe ......")` function which loads a pdf template and outputs a new processed pdf file and sent to browser.

The combination of `PdfProcess.exe` and `PHP passthru(...)` function works on my Windows Apache/PHP server in my development system.

Now I got to use this in my Ubuntu Hardy. I googled on how to run a .NET app using Mono in Ubuntu and I found [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page).

And I've been trying to install Mono 2.0.1, 2.2 since 2 days, still figuring out the installation error and I'm getting no-where.

So, before spending anymore time on it I want to know what are the things to install to make work the PHP passthru(...) function and PdfProcess.exe work together?

Only installing Mono will work or do I have to install XSP and MCS as well?

And which version of Mono is required to run this PdfProcess.exe .NET 2 based module?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use Moma to check if you PdfProcess.exe can run without a problem on Mono.

http://mono-project.com/Moma

Second, install Mono on Ubuntu is hard. There is no official support yet. You may try other Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Apache? most probably.

You need to install and configure mod_mono to run Asp.net applications.

On Mono project site you can find [details instructions to configure mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)

I suggest you to look in repo(Add/remove program ) for mono, but there will be older version.

Is PdfProcess.exe is .net application? if yes than First check it with [MoMa](http://www.mono-project.com/Moma)

If PdfProcess.exe is not .net application than you have find replacement of it.